# ffmpeg how to trigger color changes based on time

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is to modify the color of an image overlay at specific times in a video file.
I use AI to determine the emotion of the subtitles, and change the background color based on emotions.
I've already figured out the subtitle.srt usage, and I know when to trigger which color.
I need a clue on how to do it in ffmpeg.

Comment: This is the command I'm using ./ffmpeg -i p1cart40.mp4 -i "auth1_50x50.png" -i "auth2_50x50.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480[bg0];  [bg0][1:v]overlay=15:15[bg1];  [bg1]subtitles=MySubtitle.srt:force_style='Fontsize=10,FontName=opensansregular.ttf,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&,Alignment=10'[bg2]; [bg2]drawtext=text='www.MaiClips.com':fontsize=10:fontfile=opensansregular.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=300:y=300[bg3]; [bg3][2:v]overlay=500:15:format=auto,drawtext=text='This is the tittle bar':fontsize=10:fontfile=opensansregular.ttf:fontcolor=white:x=100:y=15" -c:v libx264 output.mp4

Comment: is there something similar to subtitle.srt to control the color of an overlay, so I can synchronize it with subtitles?

Comment: Which of the files in your example command is supposed to have color changes?

Comment: The subtitle file will have the emotion word trigger, but I can put the emotions in a secondary subtitle file if it will make it possible.

Comment: I've created an emotionsubtitle.srt that has a text of "____" which I align with an image on layout, and in the file I have different color for each line. example of 
 few lines of emotionsubtitle.txt below: My alternative solution is to change the color of this line which is placed under an image to change colors with time. but this is a hack, I really would like to show different emoji 1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:39:54,000
<font color="cyan">______</font>

2
00:39:54,000 --> 01:19:30,000
<font color="grey">______</font>

3
01:19:30,000 --> 01:59:20,000
<font color="yellow">______</font>

Comment: I still don't understand which element needs the color change. The subtitles? `p1cart40.mp4`? `auth1_50x50.png`? `auth2_50x50.png`? drawtext?

Comment: I'm sorry, Let me reset, I provided too much information. I'd like to represent emotions through colors. I have been successful in making the text change color based on the emotion of that sentence through subtitles function. I would like to change the background color of the author's image, by swapping the image with similar image that has a different color background.   I don't know how to do this in ffmpeg. I know the exact time of emotion change for every sentence, but need a clue on how to make this work.

Comment: Seems like the real question is *"How to replace overlay image at specific times?"* and color has nothing to do with it.

Comment: YES. is ffmpeg the right tool for this?

Comment: Yes. One method is to use the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) in overlay.